# Is there a minhag to smell besamim on shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, smell

Is there a minhag to smell besamim on shabbos?(for reasons other than the 100 brochos)

Comment: Wwlcome to mi yodeya user 12660, I know that some people has this this minhag, and that it is linked to the 100 brochos.

Comment: There's a kabbalistic minhag to sniff haddassim specifically. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://asimplejew.blogspot.com/2010/10/minhag-of-smelling-spices-and-hadasim.html):

Chassidim develped a custom to smell myrtle branches on Shabbat eve, based on Talmud Shabbat 118b, relating that R. Shimon bar Yochai saw a man running to his home with 2 myrtle branches. The man explained to Rashb"i that one was for "Zachor" and the other for "Shamor".